Oracle: restrict access to table until procedure is done
I have a complex procedure and a table that this procedure updates. There is also a web service for the Administrator who must run the procedure, and a web service for Operators who actively work with the table (all types of DML operations).
The task is simple: I need to limit any Operator operations on the table until the procedure launched by the Administrator is completed.
My proposal for solving this problem: create a Control table with the procedure Launch flag. When the Administrator launches the procedure in his web service, I can set a flag in the control table and register a One-time job on the db-server with a launch delay of ~5 seconds (so that all unprocessed transactions from the Operators have time to be processed) and in the same job, after the procedure is finished, remove the procedure launch flag. In the operators' web service, before starting the next operation, check the flag in the control table and prohibit the operation if the flag indicates that the procedure is currently running.
Question: how reliable is this solution and are there any other solutions for this problem?

How much control do you have over the Operators code? You could have the Operators do a select ... for update nowait and have them retry if they get a ORA-00054 resource busy exception.

@MartinSchapendonk, I have little control over Operators web service. It uses ORM (Entity Framework Core) and as far as I understand from my colleagues who work on this service, this ORM does not support pessimistic locks. Therefore, I am forced to look for a solution within the Administrator service and the tools available at the database level.

You could create views of all tables, have EF core work on views instead of tables, catch DML statements with an instead of trigger and do the check for the lock in your trigger. This would make it transparant from an EF Core perspective (although they would need to implement the retry logic themselves).

@MartinSchapendonk, Your proposal looks interesting. I will definitely discuss it with my colleagues. Thank you very much!

Good luck! To enforce this structure and prohibit DML directly on your tables you should also grant rights on the views only to the EF core user.

Oracle lets you literally lock the table, e.g.
SQL> lock table emp in exclusive mode;

Table(s) Locked.

SQL>

That will restrict access to it (not to the readers, though). Lock will automatically be released once you commit (or rollback).
The lock is much more than my simple example; have a look at documentation (I guess you might be interested in its wait parameter).

Thanks for the reply! Maybe I used LOCK TABLE incorrectly, but the problem with this approach is that DML operations wait for the lock to be released in the Operators service, and when the lock is released, the transactions that were "hanging" for a while are still executed. The difficulty is that after the procedure finishes, all "hanging" actions are considered incorrect, because the procedure can update anything and the Operators must either agree with the changes or repeat their actions.

You may also need to specify a DDL lock timeout—the number of seconds a DDL command waits for its required locks before failing using DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT parameter at the system level, or at the session level.
Catch and treat the resource busy error message in the application.
ORA-00054: resource busy

EXCEPTION
   WHEN RESOURCE_BUSY
      THEN
. . . 

